# Access DB Context in program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Is there a way to access the DB context of a .NET Core application in the `program.cs` file? I am basically looking to configure Kestrel with specific options that are stored in the database so I would need access to the database context.

I am basically trying to do something like this:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSentry()
            .UseKestrel(opts =>
                 {
                    opts.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        var storedCert = _db.Certificates.First(c => c.Id == 1);
                        var certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(storedCert.CertificatePfx);
                        var certPassword = storedCert.CertificatePassword;

                        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, certPassword);

                        listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is about how to create a scoped service within a singleton ：

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(opt => {
                var sp = opt.ApplicationServices;
                using(var scope = sp.CreateScope() ){
                    var dbContext=scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
                    var e= dbContext.Certificates.FirstOrDefault();
                    // now you get the certificates
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to do the following:

```
var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();

var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();       

//get a new WebHostBuilder
CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
//Configure here using the ctx
.Build()
.Run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the below code worked for me for .net 6

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = service.GetService<MyAppDbContext>();
}
```

Using this you can use not only get dbcontext but any other service.
Consider below example for usermanager object of identity class:

```
var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to go about doing this. You need to manually build up the configuration for the DB context then instantiate the context, then you are able to use it. Here is the code in case anyone is in this position.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSentry()
                .UseKestrel(opts =>
                {
                    opts.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOpts =>
                    {
                        //Create the configuration to read from appsettings.json
                        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(
                                Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json"))
                            .Build();

                        //Create the DB Context options
                        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>()
                            .UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionString:Development"]);

                        //Create a new database context
                        var context = new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

                        //Get the certificate
                        var certificate = context.Certificates.First();
                    });
                });
```

Comment: That's not a good way. You're building the configuration twice. Also there's no need to create the DbContext manually . The only trick is to create a scoped service within a singleton : `.UseKestrel(opt => {
        var sp = opt.ApplicationServices;
        using(var scope = sp.CreateScope() ){
            var dbContext=scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
            var c= dbContext.Certificates.First();
        }
    });`

Comment: @itminus - That works perfectly - thank you so much. If you'd like to post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Done :)

Answer (score 0):

For build deb context and `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(option =>
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBCS")));
```

Comment: add ctor in db context -    public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Connection strings -      "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB": "Server=DESKTOP-EN9GE2A\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=StudentRegDB; Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}

Comment: access db context -builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get service using following code

```
 var host = BuildWebHost(args);

DbContext context = host.Services.GetService<DbContext>();
```

and code to register your **DbContext** in **startup.cs** is as follows

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: I need to use the context within the configuration of `CreateDefaultBuilder` so this will not work.

Answer (score -2):

[1] Connection String -
a) "ConnectionStrings": {
"DB": "Server=SQL Server Name; Database=Name Of Database; Trusted_Connection=True;Trust Server Certificate=true"
}

Comment: [2] Add DbContext -
      public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }                                                                                                                                                       
                     [3]
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));